# Another if statement before it goes to the second if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a function where 2 players with difference in weight will be joined in 1 array. As we can see on the result of the snippet,

> **Player 2 and Player 5 are on the same array. It happens because player 2 has 1905 weight and player 5 has 1910 weight**. That means their weight difference didn't exceed diference of 15. They only have 5 weight difference.

```js
const source = [
      { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 },
      { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1900 },
      { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player3', weight: 1905 },
      { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player4', weight: 1905 },
      { entryID: 5, entryName: 'player5', weight: 1910 },
      { entryID: 6, entryName: 'player6', weight: 1910 },
      { entryID: 7, entryName: 'player7', weight: 1920 },
      { entryID: 8, entryName: 'player8', weight: 1930 },
      { entryID: 9, entryName: 'player9', weight: 1935 },
      { entryID: 10, entryName: 'player10', weight: 1940 },
      { entryID: 11, entryName: 'player11', weight: 1955 },
      { entryID: 12, entryName: 'player12', weight: 1960 },
    ]
    
    function newCombine(data, difference) {
      let nonMatched = [...data]
      const groups = {}
    
      for (let i = 0; i < nonMatched.length - 1; i++) {
        const first = nonMatched[i]
    
        inner: for (let j = nonMatched.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
          const second = nonMatched[j]
          const delta = Math.abs(first.weight - second.weight)
    
//I think i need to add more if statement here before it goes to if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {

          if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {
            const groupKey = `${first.weight}_${second.weight}`
            groups[groupKey] = [first, second]
            nonMatched = nonMatched.filter(
              obj => obj.entryID != first.entryID && obj.entryID != second.entryID
            )
            i = -1
            break inner
          }
        }
      }
      return { ...groups, ...nonMatched }
    }
    
    
    const a = newCombine(source, 15)
    console.log(a)
```

Now my target is, how can i prioritize the players with the same weight joined in array?

This is my target output:

```
    {
    1900_1900: [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900
  }, {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900
  }],
    1905_1905: [{
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: "player3",
    weight: 1905
  }, {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: "player4",
    weight: 1905
  }],
    1915_1920: [{
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: "player5",
    weight: 1915
  }, {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: "player6",
    weight: 1920
  }],
    1930_1940: [{
    entryID: 7,
    entryName: "player7",
    weight: 1930
  }, {
    entryID: 8,
    entryName: "player8",
    weight: 1940
  }]
```

We can see here that the players who has same weight are joined in the same array. They're being prioritized by the function followed by the players with the weight difference.

How can i achieve this target of mine? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps this solution (which is not quite optimal) can help you.

Before processing the data, you should sort the array of objects in ascending order using the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method (by the "weight" property) and, accordingly, in callback, you decide how objects with the same "weight" property should be sorted.

In the code below, two different examples are displayed: the usual one and for an example with a special callback function, thanks to which elements with the same "weight" are displayed in reverse order.

```js
const source = [
  {
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900,
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900,
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: "player3",
    weight: 1905,
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: "player4",
    weight: 1905,
  },
  {
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: "player5",
    weight: 1910,
  },
  {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: "player6",
    weight: 1910,
  },
  {
    entryID: 7,
    entryName: "player7",
    weight: 1920,
  },
  {
    entryID: 8,
    entryName: "player8",
    weight: 1930,
  },
  {
    entryID: 9,
    entryName: "player9",
    weight: 1935,
  },
  {
    entryID: 10,
    entryName: "player10",
    weight: 1940,
  },
  {
    entryID: 11,
    entryName: "player11",
    weight: 1955,
  },
  {
    entryID: 12,
    entryName: "player12",
    weight: 1960,
  },
];

function combine(
  data = [],
  different = 15,
  maxGroupSize = 2,
  sortedStatement = (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight
) {
  const sortedData = [...data].sort(sortedStatement); // "weight" must be in ascending order

  const dataGroups = sortedData.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const findedAccItem = acc.find(
      (accItem) =>
        accItem.length < maxGroupSize && // if the array is not filled
        accItem[0].weight + different >= item.weight && // and if the minimum is in the acceptable range
        !accItem.find((obj) => obj.entryName === item.entryName /* || obj.entryID === item.entryID */) // and if there are no matches
    );
    if (findedAccItem) {
      findedAccItem.push(item);
    } else {
      acc.push([item]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const namedDataGroups = dataGroups.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    // added an index as a prefix because the keys can match
    const key = [index, ...item.map((item) => item.weight)].join("_");
    acc[key] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return namedDataGroups;
}

// default example
console.log("Example #1: ", combine(source));

// advanced example: displaying elements in reverse order if the weight properties are equal
console.log(
  "Example #2:",
  combine(source, 15, 2, (a, b) =>
    a.weight === b.weight ? b.entryID - a.entryID : a.weight - b.weight
  )
);
```

Note that a prefix has been added to the keys in the resulting object, since the keys of the previous type can match and therefore be overwritten (in the example, this is seen in the keys "0_1900_1905" and "1_1900_1905"). This is done just for an example, but in the code you can easily alter it to a structure that is convenient for you.

Comment: Thank you for this one. I'll study about it and apply it on my function. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I have tested your function and it works fine. Can i have an additional? I forgot to mention that... "entries who has the same entryname should not be joined in 1 array".

What i mean is. entryName: Player1 1900 and entryName: Player1 1900 should not be in the same array because they have the same entryName.

Comment: If we look again on my old codes. We can see this line 

 if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {

This function checks the data if they have the same entryname, then it shouldn't be joined in the same array. How can i apply this function to yours? Thank you so much

Comment: @Dark, I have updated both the example and the answer itself, taking into account your comment, and also added some explanatory comments to the code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Oleg. I have tested it out and it works perfectly in my end.

Appreciated and have a nice day.